# Vim: How do I override global settings?

Tags: vim

In `~/.vimrc`, I have two lines:

```
set textwidth=80
au FileType vim set textwidth=200    " I like to live dangerously
```

When I open vim, `set tw` shows `200` as it should. But when I `:source ~/.vimrc`, `set tw` shows `80`. This is made even more clear with `set colorcolumn=+1`

This is a particularly annoying edge case, since the one time I'm going to be constantly sourcing `.vimrc` is while editing `.vimrc`, otherwise I would probably just ignore the issue.

My questions: Am I doing anything wrong? If so, how would I stop `tw` from changing every time I `:so ~/.vimrc`?

Answer (score 1):

Since that is just a corner case for `.vimrc`, I would work around this with a conditional that reapplies the local setting to a Vimscript buffer:

```
set textwidth=80
au FileType vim setlocal textwidth=200    " I like to live dangerously
if &filetype ==# 'vim'
    setlocal textwidth=200
endif
```

Note that you should use `:setlocal` instead of `:set` for the buffer-local option. Otherwise, any new, non-Vimscript buffer you'll open after editing a Vimscript will wrongly inherit the larger textwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a great solution, but you could explicitly guard against it.

```
if !exists("g:conf_loaded")
  " do things you only want to do once
  set textwidth=80
  let g:conf_loaded = 1
endif
```

Or you could detect if `textwidth` is still at its default value:

```
if &textwidth == 0
  set textwidth=80
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The `textwidth` setting is local to a buffer. You have an autocmd running on every buffer when the vim filetype is set. That sets the textwidth to 200 properly. Then you re-source `~/.vimrc` which sets the textwidth to 80. The FileType autocmd is no refired.

The solution is to remove the textwidth 80 line.